# Request other URL in one PHP Script

Tags: php, get

Hi i wana make a request in my script to a other page and the request have some get Parameters they come back.

(I dont wana do this with ajax only php in one script)

this should be done without redirecting to other page. I wana make this in the background to validate the data they come back from the other page in one script

www.example.de -> request www.exampel2.de/?ex=1

then i will validate the example2 get parameter in example.de

Any solutions?

Comment: Why not tell us what you've tried instead of asking the SO community to do the work for you?

Comment: file (if configured to do so) the curl extension, etc. can all help with this.

Comment: The cause of, and solution to, all of life's problems: AJAX

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `cURL` functions will allow you to perform advanced HTTP requests. You can use `file_get_contents`  to access REST APIs: